# Setup java web application to run each SQL script only once

Tags: java, sql, spring, maven, web-applications

**Question**

Together with my friends from university I'm making Web Application and We faced following problem recently. The server is synchronized with remote repository (git). Everyone can run application locally and has own local database on his local machine. There is database on web-hosting plugged to application on server. When someone wants to change something in database, he writes an sql script push it to the repository run it, then run it on server and make sure that every each developer execute it too. That seems to be very uncomfortable for us.

**Bad idea**

The solution would be plugging everyone to the same database. But IMHO this is the bad idea because of:

- We would need to buy another web-host for SQL because, that which is running currently is for worldwide users. For safety, testing reasons we would need another one.
- Having a database that is visible for the world, protected with simple password only, seems to be dangerous for me. Current database is configured to be visible only locally (locally relatively to server of course), so generally it is visible for the web server and to developers via ssh if needed.
- Performance reason. Connecting to remote database instead of local would be over a dozen times slower considering it for developer use (more complicated queries, tesing site a lots of jUnit testing) would be incredibly painful solution.

**Good idea**

Some time ago I worked in company that problem was resolved as follows. There was a maven plugin configured to run each sql script in specified directory only once during application build (mvn clean install) i.e. it remembers which script was executed already and leave it. Consider that someone wants to change something in database new column for example. Then he writes script push it to the repository then he don't worry about anything because script would be automatically executed for him, sever and every other developer during application build.

**How to do it**

Unfortunately I can't find that plugin or configuration. To be honest I cannot find anything related to my problem on the web which is surprising because it seems to be a common problem for me. So can I do it by some Maven plugin? Maybe there is way to do it by proper Spring configuration. In case I would forced to do it manually (in Java at the application start) what tools do I need, any advice, class patterns?

Looking forward for your help. Also sorry for my English I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but maybe the company you worked for used liquibase or flyway.
In case of liquibase which can be used via maven as well, information can be found here: http://www.liquibase.org/, specifically for the maven integratation here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/index.html

Spring comes with a liquibase integration as well, information can be found here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html or in addition, if you're using spring boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Another possible solution for database migration is flyway: your entry point for documentation: http://flywaydb.org/

Comment: indeed it was liquibase, you even guessed right that i'm using spring-boot